# Circle topology of Nodes for distributed system with WebSockets - How to mark all Nodes when topology healthy?

Tags: node.js, algorithm, nodes, distributed-system

Let's assume circular topology of `Nodes` where each `Node` is connected with next (right/clockwise) `Node` by WebSocket bidirectional tunnel. I will speak about 5 `Nodes`, but minimum is 3.

Nodes will end up in this configuration after initial setup:
[image: Nodes]
`leftNode` and `rightNode` are references to given WebSocket live tunnel between two `Nodes`.

Spawning of `Nodes` works like this:

1. `Node` is spawned with constructor(id, leftNodeId, rightNodeId)
2. WebSocket server is started
3. `Node` start trying endlessly to connect to next `Node` by given id.
4. When connection is made `Node`saves reference to tunnel into `rightNode` and right node saves it into `leftNode`

Nodes can spawn randomly...

How to set `circleHealthy` variable on all `Nodes` when circle is complete?

Answer (score 1):

I would have every node transmit its identifier to its right, and forward such messages from its left, adding its own identifier (it might be worth trying to consolidate such messages, using some sort of timeout, but with a maximum of 5 nodes, this is not a big deal). When you see your own identifier coming back from your left, you know that it has passed through every other node.